# Trefethen and Bau 24.4: Proof when the norm of $e^{At}$ decays.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prompt:

For an arbitrary $A \in C^{m \times m}$ and norm $\| \cdot \|$, prove that
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} \|e^{tA}\| = 0 \Leftrightarrow \alpha(A) < 0
$$
where $\alpha(\cdot)$ is the *spectral abscissa* of its input (e.g., $\alpha(A) = \underset{k}{max} \, \Re(\lambda_k)$).

Comment: Are you sure that you are quoting the book correctly? The eigenvalues of a complex matrix are non-real in general. The expression $\max_k\lambda_k$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks @user1551 for catching the mistake. I fixed it. We should take the real part of the eigenvalue when calculating $\alpha(A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start by proving the forward case. Let $U T U^{\dagger}$ be the Schur
factorisation of $A$. Take the exponential of $At$,

$$
  e^{tA} = U e^{tT} U^{\dagger}
$$

The eigenvalues of $e^{tA}$ are those of $e^{tT}$. Moreover, they
make up the diagonal of $e^{tT}$ and have the form $e^{t \lambda}$, where
$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.
Additionally, $e^{tT} = 0$ because $\|e^{tA}\| = 0$. It follows that
$\forall \lambda, \lim_{t \to \infty} e^{t \lambda} = 0$, which is true
when $\Re(\lambda) < 0$.

For the converse case, we first factorize $A$ using its Jordan form.

$$
  A = M J M^{-1}
$$
Take the exponential of $At$,
$$
      e^{At} = M e^{J} M^{-1}
$$
$J$ can be written as a sum of diagonal matrix $\Lambda$, which contains
the eigenvalues of $A$, and a
[superdiagonal](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superdiagonal.html)
matrix $N$. $\Lambda$ and $N$ commute, so we can write
$$
  e^{At} = M e^{Nt} e^{\Lambda t} M^{-1}
$$
We further decompose $e^{\Lambda t}$ as a sum of outer products
$$
  e^{\Lambda t} = \sum_i \exp(t \lambda_i) \vec{e_i} \vec{e_i}^T
$$
where $\vec{e_i}$ denotes the vector with 1 in the $i$th coordinate and 0s elsewhere.

As $t \to \infty$, $e^{\Lambda t}$ must be 0 because $\Re(\lambda_i) < 0$. Hence, $\forall x, e^{At} x = 0$, and $\|e^{At}\| = 0$.